# Box API V2 /collaborations?status=pending is not providing item details

Tags: box-api

I am using BOX-API V2 **/collaborations?status=pending** to get the pending collaborations folder details. But as per the documentation, http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-get-pending-collaborations, the response will have the item details. But I am getting null in the item details response even though I have a collaborations folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug on our end. We're working on fixing it. You can email in to API AT box.com if you'd like to be updated on the progress we make.

Comment: Is there any estimate on when this might be fixed?